# Why does double.tryparse return false when parsing string input from console.ReadLine();

Tags: c#

Newbie here, any help understanding is appreciated. First experience with tryparse.

In this instance:

```
do
{
    Console.Write("What is the temperature (in degrees Fahrenheit): ");
    outcome = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tempf);
    if (outcome == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
    }

} while (outcome == false);
```

A user input of 'stack' would return a `boolean` 'false' value, whereas an input such as '100' would return as 'true'.
I am under the impression that `double.TryParse` would only return `true` if the user input is of `string` type, as this would be a successful parse.

Comment: `double.TryParse` takse a `string` and tries to convert it to `double`. So the string *must* contain only digits. "100" is a `string` that contains only numbers an thus can be parsed. "stack" is a `string`, but contains chars that are not digit, and thus cannot be parsed

Comment: The `"100"` that was read from the input *is* a string. A string that can be parsed to a double value `100.0`.

Comment: If `double.TryParse` returned `true` *only* there would be *no reason* to return it all

Answer (score 1):

From msdn :

> `Double.TryParse` Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision
>   floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded or failed

So as long as conversion is possible it would return true. For example user input is "123X" will fail try parse.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `double.TryParse` which means you are trying to parse inputed value to a double value. TryParse returns true if this can be done or it returns false.

As per your inputs, for user input of 'stack', TryParse is trying to parse it to a double value which is not a valid conversion and its failing and hence returning false. And for input such as '100', TryParse can do that perfectly.

Here is [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) for it